# OOP performance in .NET web applications

Tags: .net, performance, object

Just a general question, Im a new developer but very used to working with objects. Now Ive been creating my classes etc in my web project and am now wondering if theyre not simply taking up too much memory/processing power when a large amount of users access the site?

I mean, is something like LINQ not too intensive for a web application?

The web app is coming along nicely but am worried about performance.

Comment: Linq is used on StackOverflow and StackExchage. Seems to be ok for it.

Comment: You need to learn to profile your application rather than randomly speculate.

Comment: ASP.NET itself is very object oriented. As long as you're not doing anything stupid, like storing large objects in session state you have nothing to worry about. + 1 for profiling too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be prematurely optimizing your code.  OOP/LINQ can give you a very good, clear design. This is infinitely more important than performance at this point in your development (since you are a new developer).  Worry about performance down the road. After all, what you do now to improve performance may be irrelevant in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer general questions with anything other than general responses, but if you have modern hardware, and "reasonable" performance requirements, I wouldn't worry about this at all (Hexxagonal's answer is spot on).

In general, the performance bottleneck for most web applications is not the web server CPU or memory - and it's cheap and efficient to upgrade that by adding additional server farm. The database is far more likely to become your bottleneck.

My general advice is to design for maintainability first off, and only worry about performance once you know you have a problem; then measure and identify the bottleneck before you try to optimize.

I've worked on many .Net web apps, with very large numbers of visitors, and I've never once wished I'd reduced the object orientation in my design.

Comment: Hi Neville, many thanks for your post. I've been working as a SharePoint administrator and jumped ship to a SharePoint developer. Now my organisation wants an external website based on SharePoint, and I've only done intranets before, so this is totally new for me. In this situation, sadly, additional servers to the farm are actually very very costly as you would have to pay a SharePoint license for each (very expensive).

Comment: Ah - well, that's an important bit of context. Yes, licensing cost can play a role here - but even then, it's often cheaper to put more servers in the farm than optimize the web application, as long as you haven't done anything silly. On the other hand, a public-facing website in Sharepoint will face a whole bunch of other performance issues - the Sharepoint framework effectively controls a lot of the page generation, and that can be hard to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there's nothing wrong with OOP. However, as you mention LINQ, you might want to have a look at [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) , or listen to the [respective podcast episode](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast262TheRiseOfTheMicroORMWithSamSaffronAndRobConery.aspx) by Scott Hanselman. LINQ has a few performance issues, and if performance is really an issue, you should know the alternatives.